# How can I replace int values in a dictionary C#

Tags: c#

I am wondering how I could replace int values in a dictionary in C#.
The values would look something like this.

- 25,12
- 24,35
- 12,34
- 34,12

I was wondering how I could only replace one line. For example if I wanted to replace the first line with a new value of 12,12. And it wouldn't replace any of the other '12' values in the dictionary.

Comment: Please show code - it in not possible to guess what does not work without it.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. What do you mean by replace? What dictionary are you talking about? Is it `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`? In that case: You only can have one entry per key.

Comment: i hope you mean one object per key. since a value object can be a list or an array. (Not to be picky ^^)

Comment: Are you trying to replace keys or values?

Comment: I would love to have a more detailed example of your problem.

Comment: Question is not clear. Please mention the input dictionary and the result dictionary after the operation you mentioned.

Comment: Please, show what you have tried, when asking a question

Answer (score 3):

A `Dictionary<TInt, TValue>` makes use of what are known as indexers. In this case, these are used to access elements in the dictionary by key, hence:

`dict[25]` would return `12`.

Now, according to what you want to do is to have a key of `12` and a value of `12`. Unfortunately, you cannot replace entries in a dictionary by key, so what you must do is:

```
if(dict.ContainsKey(25))
{
    dict.Remove(25);
}
if(!dict.ContainsKey(12))
{
    dict.Add(12, 12);
}
```

**Note:** In the values you supplied, there is already a key-value pair with `12` as its key, so you would not be allowed to add `12,12` to the dictionary as `if(!dict.ContainsKey(12))` would return false.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing it not using a dictionary? Because for what I need to do it uses x and y positions and if I have the same X or Y I don't want it to replace the wrong value.

Comment: `List<Tuple<int, int>>` or if you're `using System.Drawing` maybe `List<Point>`.

Comment: "you cannot replace entries in a dictionary by key" - using the indexer? Of course you can. There's no need to go through that ContainsKey/!ContainsKey dance. It still doesn't let you have both 12,12 and 12,34, of course.

Comment: @shambulator What I meant was that you cannot change the key value pair `25,12` to `12,12` in one step, you would have to remove and add, and as far as I know trying to add a key that already exists will throw an `ArgumentException` and removing a key value pair by a key that doesn't exist would throw a `KeyNotFoundException`. @user2306087 as Corak said you could use a `List<Point>` or a `List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>`. A 2d `int` array might be sufficient depending on your needs.

Comment: @JurgenCamilleri Apologies, you're right - in this case, with two different keys, you would have to remove and then add. Calling `Add` with an existing key will throw, but using the indexer to do the same won't. Calling `Remove` for a nonexistent key will return `false` to indicate that the key was not found, but won't throw.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot replace the first line with `12, 12` because there is another key value pair with 12 as it's key. And you cannot have duplicate keys in a dictionary.

Anyway you may do such things like this:

```
Dictionary<int, int> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
myDictionary.Add(25, 12);
myDictionary.Add(24, 35);

//remove the old item
myDictionary.Remove(25);

//add the new item
myDictionary.Add(12, 12);
```

**EDIT:** if you are going to save some x,y positions I would suggest you creating a class named Point and use a `List<Point>`. Here is the code:

```
class Point
{
    public double X {get; set;}
    public double Y {get; set;}

    public Point(double x, double y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
List<Point> myList =new List<Point>();
myList.Add(new Point(25, 13));
```

Comment: Would there be any other way to do it (not using a dictionary)?

Comment: @user2306087 What are you looking for?

Comment: What I want to do uses x and y positions and if I have the same X or Y I don't want it to replace the wrong value.

Comment: I get the error: 'My_Project.Point' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: That is when I do "myList.Add(new Point(x,y));

Comment: Thank you so much kind sir, this has worked. Greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: @user2306087 Glad to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In Dictionaries, the keys must be unique.

In case the key need not be unique, you could use a `List<Tuple<int, int>>` or `List<CustomClass>` with `CustomClass` containing two integer fields. Then you may add or replace the way you want.